# Visual Studio addin that combines the Xaml and code behind file titles

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, computer-science, add-in, code-behind

I am tired of chasing down the code behind or the Xaml file when they get separated in the visual Studio file title bar. I realize that there are keyboard shortcuts but I once was watching a tutorial video a while back and it looked like the video author had a neat add in that would solve my issue.

The title bar above the code windows generally just show the titles of all the open documents like so; “MainWindow.xaml” or “Helper.cs”. Well what I saw in the video was each Xaml file had only one title for both the xaml and cs file, it looked like this “MainWindow  .Xaml  .cs”. The file extensions where slightly separated and you could actually click on one of the extensions and open that file.

Does anyone know an add in that would do that? Or could someone point me in the direction of addin coding? it seems like a simple thing to code. I have searched all over but I cant seem to find anything like it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Check if the below is that 
[Tabs Studio](http://www.tabsstudio.com/documentation/user_guide.html)

it is available as a trial for free.